# Download Hotlinked Images from Forum from Command Line

Tags: command-line, images, download

From the command line, is it possible to download linked images posted on forums? I want to enter the forum thread url and maybe stipulate which image hosts to detect. Also some threads will have multiple pages, so I'd like to be able to stipulate how many pages of the thread to scan for links. I don't want thumbnails, just the hotlinked images. I know how to download images from websites using Wget, but I can't get the command to download hotlinked images on forums. [ImageHost Grabber](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imagehost-grabber/) is a useful tool for this, but it requires that you visit the forum.

An example URL for a forum:

`http://exampleforum.com/t19823-springs-top.html`

Multiple pages add "p2" "p3" etc. to the URL:

`http://exampleforum.com/t19823-p2-springs-top.html`

Comment: It is possible technically but bear in mind that many forums require membership to view images hence allow downloading them.

Comment: @Nasha I'd be happy to see a solution that incorporates password credentials. But solutions that assume the forum doesn't need password credentials are welcome too.